# How does a Wifi manager encrypt profiles (WinCE)

Tags: security, wifi, windows-ce, truststore, password-storage

Hi I am trying to develop a small Wifi manager, and I have one question:

I need to encrypt the profile file when saving it in the disk, and decrypt it when loading it.

I will use a pass-phrase to do that, so how can I store my pass-phrase:
- If I store it in a file, it's to easy to dump
- If I hardcode it, it will be visible somewhere in my binary
- I am under WindowsCE, and I don't know if there is a secure store to save Data?
- I know that under Linux, we can have the trust store, and with tuning some permissions only 'root' will have access to it, and this is enough for me, is there any possibility to do something like that under WinCE?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft's Wireless Zero Config stores the WiFi keys in a registry key defined in eapol.h. `[HKLM]\Comm\EAPOL\Config`

The string is encrypted using [CryptProtectData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922939.aspx) with the `CRYPTPROTECT_SYSTEM` flag.